# Why Does The TextView Only Display The Last One getIntent().getStringExtra() Content？ Android

Tags: android

I am a beginner of Android programming and I am trying to send paragraphs of String data from MainActivity to another activity called Info activity.

I searched the intent way to send multiple String data at once between activities but it seems I can display only one (the newest one) of them on ONE TextView (displayTxt)

Here is the function for sending Intent data from MainActiviy to Info activity

The selectedItem() returns int values for spinner inputs

```
protected void setGoBtn(){
    //Texts
    rabitSyno=getString(R.string.rabit_syno);
    lifeSyno=getString(R.string.life_syno);
    poolSyno=getString(R.string.pool_syno);

    goBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.goBtn);
    goBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),Info.class);

            //send data to second activity
            if(selectedItem()==1){
                intent.putExtra("rabit_syno",rabitSyno);

                startActivity(intent.putExtra("rabit_syno",rabitSyno));
            }else if(selectedItem()==2){
                intent.putExtra("life_syno",lifeSyno);

                startActivity(intent);
            }else if(selectedItem()==3){

                intent.putExtra("pool_syno",poolSyno);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And below is my Receive method in Info activity

```
private int getTxt(){
    txt=getIntent().getStringExtra("rabit_syno");
    txt1=getIntent().getStringExtra("life_syno");
    txt2=getIntent().getStringExtra("pool_syno");
    String[] txtBox={txt,txt1,txt2};
    int i;
    //To get each movie's texts
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        if(i==0){
            displayTxt.setText(txtBox[0]);
        }else if(i==1){
            displayTxt.setText(txtBox[1]);
        }else if(i==2){
            displayTxt.setText(txtBox[2]);
            //the textView(displayTxt) only displays the txtBox[2] content
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

In other words, is it Possible To Receive Different String data with one intent From One Activity On another Activity AND Display Each text SEPARATELY (like the newly selected item's information will cover the previous selected one) On ONE TextView ONLY?

Comment: you mean to display all 3 strings in the same textView ?  displayTxt.setText(txt1+ " " + txt2+ " " + txt3);

Comment: Thanks for the replay again! I tried this and it worked....! And that's so simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No, I have 3 selections in a spinner, and each time a user can only
>   choose one item, and this item would activate the correspondent intent
>   String data transferring to info activity, and display the data onto
>   ONE TextView

Study your receive method properly and you'd see that there's no way that should work, you are using a for-loop that terminates when i is 2; the text would always end up being `txtBox[2]`.

This is a better way to send your values to the other side:

```
goBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),Info.class);

        String chosenItem = "";
        int position = 0;

        if(selectedItem()==1){
            chosenItem = rabitSyno;
            position = 0;
        }

        else if(selectedItem()==2){
            chosenItem = lifeSyno;
            position = 1;
        }

        else if(selectedItem()==3){
            chosenItem = poolSyno;
            position = 2;
        }

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("USERCHOICE", chosenItem);
        bundle.putInt("VALUE", position);

        startActivity(intent.putExtras(bundle));
    }
});
```

Your receive method can look this way:

```
private int getTxt(){
    String txt=getIntent().getStringExtra("USERCHOICE");
    displayTxt.setText(txt); //text has been set at this stage

    int i = getIntent().getIntExtra("VALUE");
    return i;
    }
```

Comment: Can I ask what would be better to put in the int part of getIntExtra("VALUE")? To create an array containing 0,1,2, and using for loop to iterate the array?

Comment: Since you're just checking for equivalence, you don't need to iterate. If and else statements would suffice.